# Reference custom layout in PowerPoint from Excel by name

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm in Excel and I'd like to reference a custom layout for a slide in PowerPoint by name. You can only refer to them by index, so I thought a function should do the trick:

```
Sub Monatsbericht()
   Dim DestinationPPT As String
   Dim PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application
   Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation

   Set PowerPointApp = New PowerPoint.Application
   DestinationPPT = "C:\VBA\Reports\MonthlyReport_Template.pptm" 
   Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open(DestinationPPT)

   Debug.Print PPLayout("CLayout1")

   'Rest of code
End Sub

Function PPLayout(clayout As String)
    Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim olay As PowerPoint.CustomLayout

For Each olay In ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts
    If olay.Name = clayout Then
        PPLayout = olay.Index
        Exit Function
    End If
Next olay

End Function
```

I get error 429: "Object creation by Activex component not possible.", highlighting the for each line in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `ActivePresentation` should be `myPresentation`,  Excel should not know the `ActivePresentation`. Also you must submit `myPresentation` as a parameter otherwise this is an empty variable in your function.

If you have a look at the [Slides.AddSlide method (PowerPoint)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slides.addslide) you see that the second parameter is not an `index` but of type `CustomLayout` so your function must return the layout instead of an `index`.

```
Public Function PPLayout(clayout As String, myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation) As PowerPoint.CustomLayout
    Dim olay As PowerPoint.CustomLayout

    For Each olay In myPresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts
        If olay.Name = clayout Then
            Set PPLayout = olay
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next olay
End Function
```

And use it like

```
Debug.Print PPLayout("CLayout1", myPresentation).Index
```

or

```
myPresentation.Slides.AddSlide(myPresentation.Slides.Count + 1, PPLayout("CLayout1", myPresentation))
```

Comment: My intention is to call the function, get the index of the sub and then add a slide with the custom layout. That requires a function, right? It should return the index. 

Your tip with submitting `myPresentation` worked, thank you. Now I'm trying to add a slide in the main sub: Set `mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.AddSlide(myPresentation.Slides.Count + 1, PPLayout("CLayout1", myPresentation))`. I get error 424: "Object required". Any idea what I have to change?

Comment: @Alex Of course you are right, it must be a function (need more coffee). See my edit. `AddSlide` needs a Layout object not an index.