# How do I turn the result of a Microsoft Form (excel) into a Power Point Slide, one result per page/slide?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, ms-forms

I am trying to create a form that will have the following text or image fields.

Rank
Full Name
Image
Birth Location
Service Dates
Branch
Story
Message

This form will go to an excel document.

I am not sure how to code the VBA so I click a button and run the code to turn all that data into multiple slides that look like:

[image]

Any help woudl be amazing

I tried copying someones code, but I couldn't figure out how it aligned the powerpoint and the excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Below the code for the basics of your question, with integrated at the bottom a function taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/55949105/18247317 to set the layout by name. It works with the layout "Two Content", you may have to edit the code if you want to use a different one.
Data has to be organized as per below screenshot, with the selection of only the cells containing values. A slide is created for every row, with the relative data within.

Reference to Excel must be added (it runs from PowerPoint):

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub celebrationSlides()
 
Dim excelApp As Excel.Application
Dim excelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim excelWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim excelSelection As Excel.Range
Dim selectedRows As Collection

Set excelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
Set excelWorkbook = excelApp.ActiveWorkbook
Set excelWorksheet = excelWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set excelSelection = excelApp.Selection

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Dim rowValues(8) As String
    
Set selectedRows = New Collection

Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pptPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim pptShape As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim pptTable As PowerPoint.Table

Set pptApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
Set pptPresentation = pptApp.ActivePresentation

For i = 1 To excelSelection.Rows.Count

        rowValues(0) = CStr(excelSelection.Cells(i, 1).Value2)
        rowValues(1) = CStr(excelSelection.Cells(i, 2).Value2)
        rowValues(2) = CStr(excelSelection.Cells(i, 3).Value2)
        rowValues(3) = CStr(excelSelection.Cells(i, 4).Value2)
        rowValues(4) = CStr(excelSelection.Cells(i, 5).Value2)
        rowValues(5) = CStr(excelSelection.Cells(i, 6).Value2)
        rowValues(6) = CStr(excelSelection.Cells(i, 7).Value2)
        rowValues(7) = CStr(excelSelection.Cells(i, 8).Value2)
        rowValues(8) = CStr(excelSelection.Cells(i, 9).Value2)
        
        selectedRows.Add rowValues


    ' Create a new slide in the PowerPoint presentation
    Set pptSlide = pptPresentation.Slides.AddSlide(pptPresentation.Slides.Count + 1, PPLayout("Two Content", pptPresentation))
    
    
    With pptSlide
    
            .Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "In Memory of " & selectedRows(i)(0) & ", " & selectedRows(i)(1)
            
            .Shapes.AddShape msoShapeRectangle, .Shapes.Title.Left, .Shapes.Title.Top, .Shapes.Title.Width, .Shapes.Title.Height / 2
            
                With pptSlide.Shapes(pptSlide.Shapes.Count)
                    .Line.Visible = msoFalse
                    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    .Top = pptSlide.Shapes.Placeholders(2).Top + pptSlide.Shapes.Placeholders(2).Height - pptSlide.Shapes(pptSlide.Shapes.Count).Height
                    .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = selectedRows(i)(7)
                    .TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignLeft
                End With
            
            
            .Shapes.AddPicture selectedRows(i)(8), msoFalse, msoTrue, .Shapes.Placeholders(1).Left, .Shapes.Placeholders(1).Top, .Shapes.Placeholders(1).Width, .Shapes.Placeholders(1).Height
            Set pptTable = .Shapes.AddTable(4, 1, Left:=.Shapes.Placeholders(3).Left, Top:=.Shapes.Placeholders(3).Top, Width:=.Shapes.Placeholders(3).Width, Height:=.Shapes.Placeholders(3).Height).Table
        
        
        
        
        
        
            
            With pptTable

            
            For j = 1 To pptTable.Rows.Count
            
                With .Rows(j)
                    .Height = 10
                End With
            
                .Cell(j, 1).Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                .Cell(j, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                .Cell(j, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoFalse
            
            Next j
            
                .Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "From: " & selectedRows(i)(1)
                .Cell(2, 1).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Service Dates: " & Format(selectedRows(i)(3), "Short Date") & " - " & Format(selectedRows(i)(4), "Short Date")
                .Cell(3, 1).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Branch: " & selectedRows(i)(5)
                .Cell(4, 1).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Story: " & selectedRows(i)(6)
        
            End With
            

                
    End With
    
    
    
Next i

End Sub


Public Function PPLayout(clayout As String, myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation) As PowerPoint.CustomLayout
    Dim olay As PowerPoint.CustomLayout

    For Each olay In myPresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts
        If olay.Name = clayout Then
            Set PPLayout = olay
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next olay
End Function
```

output:

[image]